# How do I clear the cache of Ruby Phusion Passenger in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, caching, passenger, phusion

I've tried restarting apache and the cached pages still appear, so there must be a folder someplace. I don't have a 'public/cache', so what other places should I look? Is there a URL flag that could trigger this effect as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to touch a file to have phusion clear out, like:

```
touch /webapps/mycook/tmp/restart.txt
```

See the [docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_redeploying_restarting_the_ruby_on_rails_application)

Comment: Yup, that causes a restart of the site, which saves all the other sites from restarting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in development mode.

I discovered I had to restart the apache service and clear the browser cache to get my changes to appear 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

First, have you cleared your browsers cache? You can do this through the browser menus, in options somewhere.

The next question I would ask is are you running the app in production or development mode?

Answer (score 0):

For those who come here nowadays

Now there is more abilities to restart passanger from ssh 
Here is the updated [doc](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/restart_app.html)

```
passenger-config restart-app
```

or

```
passenger-config restart-app /Users/phusion/testapp
```

and the old way which can be done if you had only FTP access

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

this one will be done not immediately, passanger will look for its modified timestamp to be changed to perform restart.

Answer (score -2):

Ctrl+F5 will forcibly reload the page, and all it's linked assets.

It's kind of like clearing the cache for just that one page.