# Sublime Text auto touch and upload file

Tags: flask, sublimetext2, passenger

I'm using Sublime text with the FTPSync plugin to develop a Flask web application deployed by Phusion Passenger.

Due to the way my web application is cached on the remote server, whenever I make a change to my actual web application I also need to change the last modified date on a file in Flask's '/tmp' folder on the web server in order for changes to my other web application's files to take effect (this based on advice from [How do I clear the cache of Ruby Phusion Passenger in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117536/how-do-i-clear-the-cache-of-ruby-phusion-passenger-in-ubuntu)).

Currently I have a 'restart.txt' in my web application's '/tmp' directory which I 'touch' (add a char/remove a char, then save) and then upload using FTPSync which causes the other changes I've FTP'd to the server to take effect.

I'm looking for a way to automatically touch that 'restart.txt' file and upload it whenever a file in my web app project is uploaded (currently anytime I 'save' a file).

Is there any way in Sublime Text 2 to script an action to automatically touch + upload a file and have that script run whenever a file is being uploaded?

Comment: Why you don't use Git to keep track of your development and upload your project files to your server easily and securely. https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Comment: I need to touch a file on a remote server. I'm not looking for a version control system. Even if I could set up a git repository on the remote host (which I can't since it's a web server managed by a hosting company to which I only have ftp and ssh access), that would be an innapropriate solution (a git project just to 'git touch' a file every commit doesn't really make sense).